# Best documentation for getting started with Wolfram Workbench in 2019

Tags: workbench

I want to create documentation for a Mathematica package using Wolfram Workbench.

I am familiar with basic package construction.  (I have been using the excellent intelliJIDEA plugin as a package construction tool for the last 2 years).

> I want to learn to make *help centre style* documentation for my packages

What are some good resources (tutorials) for getting started at this task (using *Workbench*) in 2019?

---

Mathematica version: `11.3`

**Wolfram Workbench version: `10.1.822`**

Comment: You might be better off asking on the Wolfram Community forums, where it's more likely to be seen by WRI developers who use the workbench regularly. You might also want to check out Szabolcs' [IGraph/M](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM), which takes a good stab at help centre-style documentation.

Comment: Might also be worth considering something *other* than workbench. Workbench docs aren’t up to date with modern styles and won’t be backwards compatible. You do not need Workbench to make documentation as all the features of docs notebooks have been discussed on this site.